# sed pattern find and replace lines

Tags: linux, sed

I need to use sed to search for This line

```
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

and replace it with a new 3 lines

```
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"
maxThreads="300" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75" acceptCount="100"
enableLookups="false"  connectionTimeout="60000" />
```

I used the following pattern , but i believe i missing escaping part

```
sed -i 's/ <Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />/<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"
        maxThreads="300" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75" acceptCount="100"
        enableLookups="false"  connectionTimeout="60000" />/g'
```

Advise please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that your search string does contain `/`.  I make it part of the `sed` code.
Try

```
sed -i 's|search|replace|g' file
```

And your `sed` search for a space before the string. Need to be removed:

```
s/ <
```

correct

```
s/<
```

Complete command:

```
sed -i 's|<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />|<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"     maxThreads="300" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75" acceptCount="100" enableLookups="false"  connectionTimeout="60000" />|g' file
```

Comment: Jotne  I got sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `|'

Comment: @LeoSam It was the new line within the `sed`, try now. If you need new line use `\n` in the `sed` where you like it, like this: `sed 's|search|line1\nline2|g'`

Answer (score 0):

Either, backslash the slashes in the search string (you should also do it for dots to prevent them from matching any character).

Or, use a proper XML handling tool to process XML data. For example, [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2):

```
open file.xml ;
for //Connector[@URIEncoding="UTF-8" and @port="8009"
                and @protocol="AJP/1.3" and @redirectPort="8443"] {
    set @maxThreads 300 ;
    set @minSpareThreads 25 ;
    set @enableLookups 'false' ;
    # etc.
}
save :b ;
```